# Userprofile Robocopy Backup

Tags: powershell, backup, robocopy

Hi I need to backup the userprofile of multiple PCs, can I use some global commands like %Userprofile% for my Code to backup the logged in User. Also why isn't my script properly backing up the folders which I've told him. The output is currently not accesable it just says you need more rights to open these folders.

```
$Destination=Read-Host "Please type the path directory you want to copy the backup files" #destination
$Folder=Read-Host "Please type the root name folder" #name of backup folder
$validation=Test-Path $Destination #validate the destination if it has the privileges

New-PSDrive -Name "Backup" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root $Destination #temporary folder for the backup

if ($validation -eq $True){ 

       Set-Location Backup:
}
else{

    Write-Host "Error!Run Script Again"

    break
}

    robocopy "C:\Users\user\desktop" $Destination\$Folder *.* /mir /sec
    robocopy "C:\Users\user\pictures" $Destination\$Folder *.* /mir /sec
    robocopy "C:\Users\user\documents" $Destination\$Folder *.* /mir /sec


Function Pause{

     Write-Host "Backup Sucessfull!!! `n"

}



Pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of `%Userprofile%` in PowerShell is `$Env:UserProfile`.

```
robocopy "$env:UserProfile\desktop" $Destination\$Folder *.* /mir /sec
robocopy "$env:UserProfile\pictures" $Destination\$Folder *.* /mir /sec
robocopy "$env:UserProfile\documents" $Destination\$Folder *.* /mir /sec
```

If your script is complaining about rights, It's likely that you are running at it via an account that does not have permission to the users folder. User folders are secured to the specific user by ACLs by default. You can likely get around this by running your script with Administrator rights.

Comment: Thanks I guess it worked but the problem i'm facing now is, when I look at the output

Comment: It looks like this:

Comment: Your issue is not clear to me (is it that documents is getting duplicated?). I think you should probably open a new question explaining your issue and the code/input you are using that makes it occur.